# How to get maven to resolve/attach source packages to dependencies in own/local repository?

Tags: eclipse, maven, swt

I have a local maven repository (directly in my project's SCM) for SWT as SWT has no up-to-date artifact server.

To have this I downloaded the latest release, unpacked the zip and installed the jar (the lib itself) and the sources like this to my local repository:

`mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux -DartifactId=x86_64 -Dversion=3.7.2 -Dfile=/tmp/swt.jar -Dpackaging=jar -Durl=file://tmp/myProject/lib/`

Respectively:

`mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux -DartifactId=x86_64 -Dversion=3.7.2 -Dfile=/tmp/src.zip -Dpackaging=jar -Durl=file://tmp/myProject/lib/ -Dclassifier=sources`

After that I declared this repo and the swt dependency in my project's pom and ran:

`mvn -DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true eclipse:clean`

and `mvn -DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true eclipse:eclipse`

This adds SWT to my .classpath and sets up the rest for me.
But it does not attach swt-sources.jar to the swt dependency in eclipse.

Any hints why this doesn't work?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: I use Indigo. Attaching sources to other dependencies from remote repositories works.

Comment: If you use indigo than don't use the maven:eclipse plugin anymore. Better import the project directly into Eclipse. (install m2e and m2e for wtp). Furthermore I recommend to install a Repository Manager which makes life easier.